# How to add handler to HttpSecurity during runtime?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

Normally, I would write an own WebSecurityConfig file and code something similar to this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
open class WebSecurityConfig : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    @Bean
    open fun accessDeniedHandler(): AccessDeniedHandler? {
        return CustomAccessDeniedHandler()
    }

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        ...
        http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler());
        ...
    }
}
```

**Question:** Is there any way to access the HttpSecurity object during runtime to add the accessDeniedHandler, without defining it in the configure(http: HttpSecurity) method?

Comment: I am writing a library and want to set as this library an AccessDeniedHandler. But I do not want the developer to force using my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implentation to continue to configure, instead I thought about just somehow setting this AccessDeniedHandler.

Answer (score -1):

you are doing a classic mistake that many make while coding spring boot.

here you are registering a custom access denied handler as a bean which will automatically be picked up by the ApplicationContext.

```
@Bean
open fun accessDeniedHandler(): AccessDeniedHandler? {
    return CustomAccessDeniedHandler()
}
```

Then here, you are manually registering the same `AccessDeniedHandler` you know, the one you a couple of rows just above registered to be automatically picked up by the context and inject where needed.

```
http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler());
```

There is absolutely no need to both automatically register and manually register the same class. You are basically doing the same thing twice.

If you wish to make a library, you should write a starter that uses the first code (registering the `AccessDeniedHandler`as a bean) and the ApplicationContext will pick up that bean and use it automatically.

***You dont need to set it manually if you have already registered it as a bean***